# Array associativo Estado e Cidade Combobox em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, array-associativo

Estou tentando montar esse array associativo, no caso do combobox for o estado de São Paulo, tem que mostrar 5 cidades de São Paulo, se for Rio de Janeiro, mostra as 5 cidades do Rio de Janeiro.

HTML

```
<select id = "estados">
    <option></option>
</select>

<select id = "cidade">  
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById("estados"); 
var cidade = document.getElementById("cidade"); 
var options = ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro"]; 
var cidade1 = ["São Paulo", "Itápolis", "Araraquara", "Ribeirão Preto", "Jacareí"];
var cidade2 = ["Rio de Janeiro", "Niteroi", "Petropolis", "Belford Roxo", "Nova Iguaçu"];
```

No código a seguir ele trás todos os estados, até aqui tudo bem.

```
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    //console.log(el)
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Retornando perfeitamente os estados no combobox.
O que eu quero agora é que quando eu selecionar o estado mostre as cidades no outro combobox, quando for o Rio ele mostre as cidades do Rio e quando Selecionar São Paulo mostre as cidades de São Paulo.
Então fiz isso, porém não retorna nada

Javascript

```
if(select){

    var t = document.getElementById("estados");
    var selectedText = t.options[t.selectedIndex].text;

    if(selectedText == 'São Paulo'){
        for(var j = 0; j < cidade1.length; j++) {
            var opt = cidade1[j];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            cidade.appendChild(el);
        }   
    }

    if(selectedText == 'Rio de Janeiro'){
        for(var j = 0; j < cidade2.length; j++) {
            var opt = cidade2[j];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            cidade.appendChild(el);
        }   
    }

}
```

Aproveitei a variável select, se ela existir entra no if, porém a variável selectedText que fiz para receber o valor do combobox do estado ela retorna vazia. Antes eu tinha deixando dentro do for, ai repetia o campo vazio 5 vezes, tirei de dentro do for ele repete um vez mas ainda sim vazio.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duas sugestões:

- cria uma função para poderes reutilizar código
- cria um objeto onde as chaves são os nomes dos estados, assim fica tudo organizado e dependente da estrutura do JSON

Assim o JSON pode crescer e ter *N* estados/cidades sem precisares de mexer mais no código.

```js
var selectEstados = document.getElementById("estados");
var selectCidades = document.getElementById("cidade");
var cidades = {
  "São Paulo": ["São Paulo", "Itápolis", "Araraquara", "Ribeirão Preto", "Jacareí"],
  "Rio de Janeiro": ["Rio de Janeiro", "Niteroi", "Petropolis", "Belford Roxo", "Nova Iguaçu"],
  "Rio Grande do Sul": ["Porto Alegre", "Uruguaiana", "Passo Fundo"]
};

function adicionarOptions(select, options, chosen) {
  select.innerHTML = options.reduce((html, option) => {
    return html + `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`;
  }, '<option disabled selected value>Escolha...</option>')
}

var estados = Object.keys(cidades);
const estadoInicial = estados[0];
adicionarOptions(selectEstados, estados, estadoInicial);
selectEstados.addEventListener('change', function() {
  adicionarOptions(selectCidades, cidades[this.value]);
});
```

```html
<select id="estados">
  <option disabled selected value>Escolha...</option>
</select>

<select id="cidade">
  <option disabled selected value>Escolha...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sucesso cara, vlw !

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo

Javascript

```
var options = {
            "São Paulo" : ["São Paulo", "Itápolis", "Araraquara", "Ribeirão Preto", "Jacareí"], 
            "Rio de Janeiro":  ["Rio de Janeiro", "Niteroi", "Petropolis", "Belford Roxo", "Nova Iguaçu"]
        }; 

        var load= function(){
                var estados = document.getElementById("estados"); 
                var chaves = Object.keys(options);

                for(var i = 0; i < chaves.length; i++) {
                    var opt = chaves[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    estados.appendChild(el);
                }
        }


        var setCidades = function (){
                var estados = document.getElementById("estados"); 
                var estado = estados.options[estados.selectedIndex].value;
                var cidades = options[estado];


                var cidade = document.getElementById("cidade");

                for(var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = cidades[i];
                    el.value =  cidades[i];
                    cidade.appendChild(el);
                }

        }
```

E no HTML:

```
<body onload="load();">
    estado
    <select id = "estados" onchange="setCidades(); return false;">
    </select>

    <br>

    cidade
    <select id = "cidade" >  
    </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

você precisa associar a mudança de estado a um evento. Do jeito como você está fazendo ele está pegando a primeira option (que está em branco) e tentando carregar as cidades, o que nunca irá funcionar. Se quiser ver isso, basta tirar as options vazias no HTML:

```
<select id = "estados">

</select>

<select id = "cidade">  

</select>
```

Agora, para resolver seu problema que é clicar e mudar, você vai precisar deu uma função que faça essa alteração sempre que o combo box sofrer mudança, algo assim:

NO HTML adicione o onchange="myFunction()", que irá chamar a função myFunction sempre que algum estado for selecionado

```
<select id = "estados" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option></option>
</select>

<select id = "cidade">  
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Na função, coloque o seu código que já estava pronto:

```
myFunction  = function (){
    if(select){
      cidade.innerHTML = "";
      var t = document.getElementById("estados");
      var selectedText = t.options[t.selectedIndex].text;

      if(selectedText == 'São Paulo'){
          for(var j = 0; j < cidade1.length; j++) {
              var opt = cidade1[j];
              var el = document.createElement("option");
              el.textContent = opt;
              el.value = opt;
              cidade.appendChild(el);
          }   
      }

      if(selectedText == 'Rio de Janeiro'){
          for(var j = 0; j < cidade2.length; j++) {
              var opt = cidade2[j];
              var el = document.createElement("option");
              el.textContent = opt;
              el.value = opt;
              cidade.appendChild(el);
          }   
      }
  }
}
```

aqui tem o exemplo completo https://jsfiddle.net/9kv5gyb3/3/

Comment: Então só tem um pequeno problema quando faz dessa maneira, é necessário remover as cidades anteriores. Seu eu escolho São Paulo irá mostrar todas as cidades de São Paulo, mas caso eu mude para o Rio irá mostrar as cidades do Rio mas as de São Paulo, seu eu mudar novamente para São Paulo irá mostra as cidades de São Paulo, do Rio e depois São Paulo de novo, e assim sucessivamente. Tem que arrumar uma maneira de zerar o segundo combobox no momento do change. Mas realmente era o que faltava no meu código, porém precisa fazer essas mudança que te falei no seu código, e acho que não sei.

Comment: Mas minha lógica estava correta só faltava isso que vc me mostrou, mas para seu código ficar perfeito, falta isso que te falei.

Comment: É verdade, faltou este detalhe. Pra corrigir basta limpar o select antes de preencher novamente, vou editar o código.

Comment: Agora ficou, perfeito !