# Preencher o select cidades de acordo com o estado

Tags: javascript

Olá, eu gostaria de que quando o usuário selecionasse um Estado, o select fosse preenchido com as cidades daquele Estado para que o usuário pudesse selecionar a sua. Eu encontrei uma forma de fazer onde você faz o cadastro das cidades no banco de dados, teria alguma forma de fazer isso sem colocar essas cidades no banco de dados, usando apenas JavaScript? Eu pensei em algo estilo o site `viacep`, que é usado para o preenchimento automático de endereço de acordo com o cep, porém não consegui achar um que faça isso para cidades e estados apenas.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Validação de dois selects](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162062/valida%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-dois-selects)

Comment: As melhores opções são: Verificar no banco de dados com ajax como tu citou, ou conectar a uma api para buscar as cidades, de qualquer forma terá um ajax para buscar e preencher selects...

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer Entendi, e você sabe se tem alguma api para esse caso?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Array associativo Estado e Cidade Combobox em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204813/array-associativo-estado-e-cidade-combobox-em-javascript) e [Filtrar estados e cidades da biblioteca cidades-estados-js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69802/3635)

Comment: Pode fazer usando a api do ibge: https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados
https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/municipios

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o JSON [deste Github](https://gist.github.com/letanure/3012978) e criar um arquivo `.js` com todas as cidades do Brasil contidas nele. Depois basta fazer uma consulta e listar as cidades pela sigla do Estado.

No exemplo abaixo coloquei apenas 2 Estados como exemplo, porque a lista de cidades é um pouco extensa:

```js
// ESTE SERIA O CONTEÚDO DO .js
var json_cidades = {
  "estados": [
    {
      "sigla": "AC",
      "nome": "Acre",
      "cidades": [
        "Acrelândia",
        "Assis Brasil",
        "Brasiléia",
        "Bujari",
        "Capixaba",
        "Cruzeiro do Sul",
        "Epitaciolândia",
        "Feijó",
        "Jordão",
        "Mâncio Lima",
        "Manoel Urbano",
        "Marechal Thaumaturgo",
        "Plácido de Castro",
        "Porto Acre",
        "Porto Walter",
        "Rio Branco",
        "Rodrigues Alves",
        "Santa Rosa do Purus",
        "Sena Madureira",
        "Senador Guiomard",
        "Tarauacá",
        "Xapuri"
      ]
    },
    {
      "sigla": "AL",
      "nome": "Alagoas",
      "cidades": [
        "Água Branca",
        "Anadia",
        "Arapiraca",
        "Atalaia",
        "Barra de Santo Antônio",
        "Barra de São Miguel",
        "Batalha",
        "Belém",
        "Belo Monte",
        "Boca da Mata",
        "Branquinha",
        "Cacimbinhas",
        "Cajueiro",
        "Campestre",
        "Campo Alegre",
        "Campo Grande",
        "Canapi",
        "Capela",
        "Carneiros",
        "Chã Preta",
        "Coité do Nóia",
        "Colônia Leopoldina",
        "Coqueiro Seco",
        "Coruripe",
        "Craíbas",
        "Delmiro Gouveia",
        "Dois Riachos",
        "Estrela de Alagoas",
        "Feira Grande",
        "Feliz Deserto",
        "Flexeiras",
        "Girau do Ponciano",
        "Ibateguara",
        "Igaci",
        "Igreja Nova",
        "Inhapi",
        "Jacaré dos Homens",
        "Jacuípe",
        "Japaratinga",
        "Jaramataia",
        "Jequiá da Praia",
        "Joaquim Gomes",
        "Jundiá",
        "Junqueiro",
        "Lagoa da Canoa",
        "Limoeiro de Anadia",
        "Maceió",
        "Major Isidoro",
        "Mar Vermelho",
        "Maragogi",
        "Maravilha",
        "Marechal Deodoro",
        "Maribondo",
        "Mata Grande",
        "Matriz de Camaragibe",
        "Messias",
        "Minador do Negrão",
        "Monteirópolis",
        "Murici",
        "Novo Lino",
        "Olho d'Água das Flores",
        "Olho d'Água do Casado",
        "Olho d'Água Grande",
        "Olivença",
        "Ouro Branco",
        "Palestina",
        "Palmeira dos Índios",
        "Pão de Açúcar",
        "Pariconha",
        "Paripueira",
        "Passo de Camaragibe",
        "Paulo Jacinto",
        "Penedo",
        "Piaçabuçu",
        "Pilar",
        "Pindoba",
        "Piranhas",
        "Poço das Trincheiras",
        "Porto Calvo",
        "Porto de Pedras",
        "Porto Real do Colégio",
        "Quebrangulo",
        "Rio Largo",
        "Roteiro",
        "Santa Luzia do Norte",
        "Santana do Ipanema",
        "Santana do Mundaú",
        "São Brás",
        "São José da Laje",
        "São José da Tapera",
        "São Luís do Quitunde",
        "São Miguel dos Campos",
        "São Miguel dos Milagres",
        "São Sebastião",
        "Satuba",
        "Senador Rui Palmeira",
        "Tanque d'Arca",
        "Taquarana",
        "Teotônio Vilela",
        "Traipu",
        "União dos Palmares",
        "Viçosa"
      ]
    }
  ]
};
// FIM DO .js

function buscaCidades(e){
   document.querySelector("#cidade").innerHTML = '';
   var cidade_select = document.querySelector("#cidade");

   var num_estados = json_cidades.estados.length;
   var j_index = -1;

   // aqui eu pego o index do Estado dentro do JSON
   for(var x=0;x<num_estados;x++){
      if(json_cidades.estados[x].sigla == e){
         j_index = x;
      }
   }

   if(j_index != -1){
  
      // aqui eu percorro todas as cidades e crio os OPTIONS
      json_cidades.estados[j_index].cidades.forEach(function(cidade){
         var cid_opts = document.createElement('option');
         cid_opts.setAttribute('value',cidade)
         cid_opts.innerHTML = cidade;
         cidade_select.appendChild(cid_opts);
      });
   }else{
      document.querySelector("#cidade").innerHTML = '';
   }
}
```

```html
<select id="estado" onchange="buscaCidades(this.value)">
   <option value="">Selecione o Estado</option>
   <option value="AC">Acre</option>
   <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="cidade">
</select>
```

Comment: Olá, muito bom o exemplo citado acima. Porém eu tenho uma dúvida, como eu poderia implementar a busca de cidades e estados diretamente do banco de dados no JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Basta uma pesquisada por aqui e encontrará varias perguntas referentes ao assunto, recentemente deixei essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/253407/60376) na pergunta [Verificar Disponibilidade do CEP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253379), como pode ver na resposta deixei alguns exemplos.

Utilizando o mesmo código e apenas adaptando conforme a sua necessidade, chega-se ao resultado:

```js
const INPUT_CIDADE = document.querySelector('#cidade');
const INPUT_ESTADO = document.querySelector('#estado');

const buscarCEP = (cep) => {
  let check = false;
  if (cep.length < 8) return;
  let url = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/'.replace('${cep}', cep);
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      res.json().then((json) => {
        if (!json.erro) {
          let cidade = json.localidade;
          let estado = json.uf;
          // Preenche os campos
          INPUT_CIDADE.value = cidade;
          INPUT_ESTADO.value = estado;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

let btnVerificarCEP = document.querySelector('#VerificarCEP');
// Adiciona o evento click
btnVerificarCEP.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let campoCEP = document.querySelector('#cep');
  buscarCEP(campoCEP.value);
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.form-group label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
  <input type="text" id="cidade" readonly disabled />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cidade">Estado</label>
  <input type="text" id="estado" readonly disabled />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cep">CEP</label>
  <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" placeholder="Informe um CEP" value="13454422" />
  <input type="button" id="VerificarCEP" value="Verificar" />
</div>
```

Comment: Haha, me ajudou de mais +, mas como fazer pra preencher automatico sem tem que clicar no botão ?