# Como apresentar valores diferentes em uma select com html e javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Opa, estou com uma dúvida em como manipular os campos de uma select e atribuir diferentes valores para a opção selecionada vou dar um exemplo do resultado que eu quero:

O usuário escolheu "Humano" gostaria que a option "Humano" me retorna os seguintes valores:

Força
Inteligencia
Velocidade

Ai o usuário escolheu "Demonio" gostaria que retornase:

Força:
Magia:
Qualquercoisa:

Não tenho conhecimento para manipular os valores gostaria que fosse com HTML e Javascript, desculpe pela dúvida leiga.

Comment: já procurou aqui no site? tem muitas perguntas relacionadas, por exemplo essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204813/array-associativo-estado-e-cidade-combobox-em-javascript

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo feedback, então, eu vejo que esses exemplos são mais complexos, o que eu pretendo é algo mais simples, os exemplos em que eu encontrei são adicionando novas OPTIONS para uma OPTION selecionada, o que eu pretendo é apenas renderizar em tela informações dependendo da OPTION selecionada.

Comment: é a mesma situação, cada vez que mudar uma option, precisa carregar outras options "relacionadas", ou então carrega todas as opções e filtra... nesse caso procure por `filter` em `javascript` que vai encontrar exemplos... de qualquer forma, tudo deve acontecer no evento "onchange" do primeiro select